# CAPTCHA error message text color is black, while it should be white

Tags: bug, design, captcha, sign-up

1. Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup, or /users/signup on any SE site.
2. Click "sign up" without filling any fields.
3. > [image]

   For readability and consistency - the color of error message should be changed to white.

<sup><sup>And also, just sayin, the capcha box sticks at the right a bit.</sup></sup>

Comment: How did you make the Captcha to appear? That's a vital missing step.

Comment: @Sha wut? Doesn't it appear for you?...

Comment: Nope. Guess the system knows you're a bot...

Comment: @Sha screenshot plz......

Comment: @Sha http://i.stack.imgur.com/O7c9Y.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jFwNa.png

Comment: @Sha strange, look at mine... you see it? But actually there should be a capcha, you realize it? Try creating an account without a captcha...

Comment: @Sha Or going to another site.

Comment: *sigh*. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SJYTX.png (no CAPTCHA)

Comment: @nicael just you that see's it :P but yeah, it should be white.